# Atomicity of a read on SPARC

Tags: multithreading, assembly, sparc

I'm writing a multithreaded application and having a problem on the SPARC platform. Ultimately my question comes down to atomicity of this platform and how I could be obtaining this result.

Some pseudocode to help clarify my question:

```
// Global variable
typdef struct pkd_struct{
    uint16_t a;
    uint16_t b;
} __attribute__(packed) pkd_struct_t;

pkd_struct_t shared;

Thread 1:
swap_value() {
  pkd_struct_t prev = shared;
  printf("%d%d\n", prev.a, prev.b);
  ...
}

Thread 2:
use_value() {
  pkd_struct_t next;

  next.a = 0; next.b = 0;
  shared = next;
  printf("%d%d\n", shared.a, shared.b);
  ...
}
```

Thread 1 and 2 are accessing the shared variable "shared". One is setting, the other is getting. If Thread 2 is setting "shared" to zero, I'd expect Thread 1 to read count either before OR after the setting -- since "shared" is aligned on a 4-byte boundary. However, I will occasionally see Thread 1 reading the value of the form 0xFFFFFF00. That is the high-order 24 bits are OLD, but the low-order byte is NEW. It appears I've gotten an intermediate value.

Looking at the disassembly, the use_value function simply does an "ST" instruction. Given that the data is aligned and isn't crossing a word boundary, is there any explanation for this behavior? If ST is indeed NOT atomic to use this way, does this explain the result I see (only 1 byte changed?!?)? There is no problem on x86.

UPDATE 1:
I've found the problem, but not the cause. GCC appears to be generating assembly that reads the shared variably byte-by-byte (thus allowing a partial update to be obtained). Comments added, but I am not terribly comfortable with SPARC assembly. %i0 is a pointer to the shared variable.

```
xxx+0xc:   ldub      [%i0], %g1             // ld unsigned byte g1 = [i0] -- 0 padded
xxx+0x10:  ...       
xxx+0x14:  ldub      [%i0 + 0x1], %g5       // ld unsigned byte g5 = [i0+1] -- 0 padded
xxx+0x18:  sllx      %g1, 0x18, %g1         // g1 = [i0+0] left shifted by 24 
xxx+0x1c:  ldub      [%i0 + 0x2], %g4       // ld unsigned byte g4 = [i0+2] -- 0 padded
xxx+0x20:  sllx      %g5, 0x10, %g5         // g5 = [i0+1] left shifted by 16
xxx+0x24:  or        %g5, %g1, %g5          // g5 = g5 OR g1
xxx+0x28:  sllx      %g4, 0x8, %g4          // g4 = [i0+2] left shifted by 8
xxx+0x2c:  or        %g4, %g5, %g4          // g4 = g4 OR g5
xxx+0x30:  ldub      [%i0 + 0x3], %g1       // ld unsigned byte g1 = [i0+3] -- 0 padded
xxx+0x34:  or        %g1, %g4, %g1          // g1 = g4 OR g1
xxx+0x38:  ...       
xxx+0x3c:  st        %g1, [%fp + 0x7df]     // store g1 on the stack
```

Any idea why GCC is generating code like this?

UPDATE 2: Adding more info to the example code. Appologies -- I'm working with a mix of new and legacy code and it's difficult to separate what's relevant. Also, I understand sharing a variable like this is highly-discouraged in general. However, this is actually in a lock implementation where higher-level code will be using this to provide atomicity and using pthreads or platform-specific locking is not an option for this.

Comment: Why are you formatting a `uint32_t` with `%lld`?  That is probably converting twice as many bytes as are in the variable.

Comment: Please just don't do this. You have the tools necessary to easily write code that's guaranteed to work. Why are you messing with code that you hope will somehow happen to work?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz This is for a lock implementation. I understand that typically this is highly frowned upon. The typical tools like pthread locks, arch-specific atomic ops, and so forth are not available to me. The current implementation relies on the shared data being aligned and st/ld being atomic in itself.

Comment: It sounds like you are attempting the impossible then. There's no portable way to do this, and you seem to have ruled out all the known non-portable ways. At best, you will make code that "happens to work" on the combination of CPU, compiler, and options you happen to compile it with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you've declared the type as `packed`, it gets one byte alignment, which means it must be read and written one byte at a time, as SPARC does not allow unaligned loads/stores.  You need to give it 4-byte alignment if you want the compiler to use word load/store instructions:

```
typdef struct pkd_struct {
    uint16_t a;
    uint16_t b;
} __attribute__((packed, aligned(4))) pkd_struct_t;
```

Note that `packed` is essentially meaningless for this struct, so you could leave that out.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. This is clearer than my answer so marking it as the accepted solution.

Answer (score -1):

Answering my own question here -- this has bugged me for too long and hopefully I can save someone a bit of frustration at some point.

The problem is that although the shared data is aligned, because it is packed GCC reads it byte-by-byte.

There is some discussion [here](http://digitalvampire.org/blog/index.php/2006/07/31/why-you-shouldnt-use-__attribute__packed/) on how packing leading to load/store bloat on SPARC (and other RISC platforms I'd assume...), but in my case it has lead to a race.

Comment: This answer doesn't really address the atomicity of operations on the SPARC platform itself.